# if/else statement isnt updating when given different values

Tags: javascript

```
const mark = {
    fullName: 'Mark Miller',
    mass: 78,
    height: 1.69,
    calcBMI: function () {
        this.bmi = this.mass / (this.height * this.height);
        return this.bmi
    }

};

const john = {
    fullName: 'John Smith',
    mass: 92,
    height: 1.95,
  calcBMI: function () {
        this.bmi = this.mass / (this.height * this.height);
        return this.bmi
    }
    
};


mark.bmi < john.bmi ? console.log(`${john.fullName}'s BMI ${john.calcBMI()} is greater than ${mark.fullName}'s BMI of ${mark.calcBMI()}`) 
: console.log(`${mark.fullName}'s BMI ${mark.calcBMI()} is greater than ${john.fullName}'s BMI of ${john.calcBMI()}`)
```

so this code DOES produce the right log, except if i change johns height or weight the if/else doesnt update and log a different result and im confused as to why

thanks!

Comment: If you're having trouble getting it working, please, for your own sake, throw that ternary in the trash and use an `if` statement.

Comment: Hint: Do you actually call that function *before* doing the test?

Comment: Can you rephrase the hint?

Comment: Your `calcBMI` function populates the very thing you're testing, and if you don't call it first, that property will not be set. You're testing `undefined<undefined` which is always `false`.

Comment: Hint: This is what [`get`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) is all about. If you defined a simple `class` you could have `get bmi`.

Comment: Im not familiar with get yet

Comment: It's worth picking up on because you can do some really amazing things with it, and the complexity is totally hidden to users of your class. Here you *must* call `calcBMI()` before anything works, which is not ergonomic.

Comment: A softer fix here is to write a `class Person` or somesuch, and implement a `constructor()` which will take in an argument set and populate the object properly, including the BMI calculation.

Comment: OKAY! that was correct i had to call the function

Comment: right im taking a course and i think hes teaching everything in a certain way so i know itll get there

Answer (score 0):

You could have just printed the `bmi` values before and after invocation on `calcBmi` member function. And in order to get desired bmi value use `getter` method.

```
const mark = {
    fullName: 'Mark Miller',
    mass: 78,
    height: 1.69,
    calcBMI: function () {
        this.bmi = this.mass / (this.height * this.height);
        return this.bmi
    }

};

const john = {
    fullName: 'John Smith',
    mass: 92,
    height: 1.95,
    calcBMI: function () {
        this.bmi = this.mass / (this.height * this.height);
        return this.bmi
    }
    
};

// You can see difference, BMI field is not created yet, but post invocation on calcBmi, bmi is giving result.
console.log(mark.bmi)
console.log(john.bmi)
console.log(mark.calcBMI())
console.log(john.calcBMI())
console.log(mark.bmi)
console.log(john.bmi)
//
mark.calcBMI() < john.calcBMI() ? console.log(`${john.fullName}'s BMI ${john.calcBMI()} is greater than ${mark.fullName}'s BMI of ${mark.calcBMI()}`) 
: console.log(`${mark.fullName}'s BMI ${mark.calcBMI()} is greater than ${john.fullName}'s BMI of ${john.calcBMI()}`)
```

Getter method example -

```
const alan = {
    fullName: 'Alan Miller',
    mass: 78,
    height: 1.69,
    get bmi() {
        return this.mass / (this.height * this.height);
    }

};
console.log(alan.bmi)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your users' bmis were showing up as `undefined` because of syntax problems. You want to use function objects for your users, and take `calcBMI()` out of the objects, because you only want to define it once:

```js
const mark = new function(){
    this.name = 'Mark Miller',
    this.mass = 78,
    this.height = 1.69,
    this.bmi = calcBMI(this.mass, this.height)
};

const john = new function(){
    this.name = 'John Smith',
    this.mass = 92,
    this.height = 1.95,
    this.bmi =  calcBMI(this.mass, this.height) 
};

function calcBMI(m, h) {
  return m / (h * h)
}

mark.bmi < john.bmi ? 
  console.log(`${john.name}'s BMI ${john.bmi} is greater than ${mark.name}'s BMI of ${mark.bmi}`) 
: console.log(`${mark.name}'s BMI ${mark.bmi} is greater than ${john.name}'s BMI of ${john.bmi}`)
```